# Front page with registered query params in URL shows blog archive instead of front page

Tags: wp-query, blog-page

WordPress version: 5.4.1

I've built a plugin that includes a shortcode. The shortcode shows a product listing and has a couple of filters. The filters trigger a page refresh through JS with query params for the filter values. If I use the shortcode on any other page than the homepage, it works fine. If I add the shortcode to the homepage and apply a filter, somehow the blog homepage is shown instead of the regular front page. (Breadcrumbs show Home > Blog)

I've registred my query vars in the `query_vars` filter:

```
add_filter('query_vars', queryVars);
    function queryVars($vars){
        $vars[] = 'queryParam1';
        $vars[] = 'queryParam2';

        return $vars;
    }
```

The problem exists with registered query vars only, if I use any other var that is not recognized by the WP query var filter, it works fine.

I've searched for similar issues and found one issue with Relevanssi and a seemingly unfixed ticket in the core issue tracker:
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/url-param-highlight-redirects-always-to-blog-page/
https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/25143

Reading up on the ticket led me to believe the `is_home` propery on the `WP_Query` class is the problem. I've tried abusing the parse_query action just to see if changing some values fixes the issue, but it doesn't seem to change anything.

```
add_filter('query_param', parseQuery);
function parseQuery(\WP_Query $wpQuery)
    {
        if($wpQuery->is_home === true){
            $wpQuery->is_home = false;
            $wpQuery->is_archive = false;
            $wpQuery->is_front_page = true;
        }

        return $wpQuery;
    }
```

So far the only working thing I have come up with is just not using WP query vars but using $_GET, which is a very bad idea.
What is causing this behavior and how can I bypass it?

My permalink setting is year/month/day/postname (second setting)

Comment: Welcome to [wordpress.se]. I hope you find the answer(s) you are looking for. Our site is different from most - if you have not done so yet, consider checking out the [tour](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) to find out how things work.

Comment: Wordpress has certain query_vars that are reserved, could you be using one of them?